# Css @media tag acting strange

Tags: html, css

I'm trying some design with the `@media` tag, on resizing the browser's window.

Normal window:

[image: normal]

Resized window:

[image: resized]

(3rd story (the one on the right) vanishes, and elements get smaller)

Problem is when I resize it back to the original size, I get:

[image: resized_back_to_original]

Code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 998px){
    ...
    .person_company{
        float: none !important;
    }
    ...
}
```

`.person_company` is these images:

[image: person_company]

I didn't post the whole `@media` code because if I remove the `.person_company` style, this problem doesn't happen. So i'm assuming it is the one that's causing the issue.

Also, note that before resize, **chrome inspect element** shows `float: right` on that element, and when resized, it shows `float: none`, and when enlarged back it shows `float: right`. So The `@media` is acting right I guess. So what is causing the problem?

Comment: try using (min) for breakpoints e.g (@media  (min-width: 998px){ ... )

Comment: Did you try scrolling the page down to check if the missing box is there? When you remove float it could end up below the floated elements.

Comment: @SalmanA There's no missing box. Please read explanation under the 2nd picture (I want the 3rd box to vanish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in Chrome that causes position problems when you resize your window. When it occurs, try just to refresh the page (F5) in the buggy position. It should then be displayed normally.

Resizing bug. :)

Maybe you could provide here more details about the size of your window before and after resizing.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. This really happens only in chrome. (And yes, refreshing fixes it...) And you can see in my code that the breakpoint is at **998px**.

Answer (score 0):

This bug occurs when you have `!important` rules for `float` and sometimes even `display`. This is because the `!important` will remain active even if the screen has been resized back up again. For now there's little to do about it, I usually try to find another way of positioning my elements. It's not like the user will sit and resize the window up and down etc. but if you really are bothered by this bug. Find another way of going about the positioning :)

Comment: But as i said, chrome's **inspect element** shows `float: right` on that element after i resize back to normal. Which means that `!important` didn't remain active